Nginx Proxy Manager behavior with unknown hosts
I have Nginx proxy manager (2.12.1 ) running on docker
I have opnsense forwarding ports 80 and 443 to NPM
I have 4 hosts set up and they are working as expected.
in the settings I created a custom page for "What to show when Nginx is hit with an unknown Host"
to test this I edited a windows hosts file to create a nonsense url that would resolve to my firewall address  then used a VPN to ensure I was coming in from outside my network.
when I used http://nonsense.com  I got the custom message I expected. 
when I use https://nonsense.com  I get the following

This site can’t be reached The webpage at https://nonsense.com/
might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
web address. ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

NOTE: I entered the url in code brackets so they would not be live links on this post
My understanding ( and that's being generous here ) is that TLS does not encrypt the main URL so I was expecting to get the same result with https that I got with http.
though looking at this more it seems ECH TLS1.3 does mask the SNI so is that what's going on here?
or is this a flaw in my testing? IE: the change to windows host file is not enough to test this correctly ?
I have tried to do my do diligence, but I've not found anything that discusses this in detail.
any help would be really appreciated,
GF

Have you considered that the nonsense URL has nothing to do with the error, rather than the invalid TLS cert? Do you get the "ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT" when you visit a valid url?

when going to a proxy host domain defined within NPM I get no errors. everything works as expected.  my understanding ( and again that's a stretch ) was that NPM -> settings -> default site  was there to handle the event that some unknown name happens to resolve to your NPM address, it cant find a match so it sends you to the  default you have set up under settings.  this appears to be the behavior if you use HTTP but gives the other error if you use HTTPS.
edit:  so as noted, I am not sure is this is an issue with how I tested it, a problem with how I set up NPM or something else.

after some research I found its impossible to do redirect HTTPS without a valid CERT. which means there is no way to use the NPM default site for HTTPS traffic. Likely this was obvious but this is not my bailiwick. Anyways, to me this means the NPM default site is only usable for testing because no body should use HTTP any more and it can't redirect HTTPS.
